# Abstract class and pure method C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, abstraction, abstract-methods

I've read in a book Stephen Prata - "C++ Primer Plus VI Edition" that in an abstract class I can write a definition of pure method. I understood that I can write for example `void pure() = 0` and then I can make a definition of that method in this class. I thought that `= 0` is only to make the class abstract and if I make another class inheriting from that class I don't have to overwrite it (I don't know if word "overwrite" is right, I meant that I wan't to hide the method from the basic class by writing a method with the same name in secondary class).

I checked it in compiler and I get warning that "it has no overrider". So if I have to overwrite this pure virtual method (with definition in abstract class) in secondary class how can I use this definition from basic class? Is it useless?

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is "_override_".

Comment: If you declare ```void pure() = 0```, you can NOT define ```void pure() { ... }``` anywhere in that class, and MUST define ```void pure() { ... }``` in any subclass (if you don't, the subclass is also considered abstract).

Comment: @Commander Coriander Salamander You are wrong. A pure virtual function may have a definition.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow You don't say... I stand corrected :)

Comment: @CommanderCorianderSalamander It's written in that book that I can use it. Probably I found solution of my problem. I can use it for example in subclass methods like this (let's assume that we have virtual pure method called "abstraMethod()" with definition from the class called "abstraClass", and subclass called just "subclass":

void subclass::abstraMethod()
{
/*[...some code...]*/
abstraClass::abstraMethod() /*calling an abstraMethod from basic class*/
/*[...some code...]*/
};
I found only one application of this. Is it any other application of this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
class Abstract {
public:
  virtual void f() = 0;
};

// A pure virtual function can still be defined.
// It has to be defined out-of-class.
void Abstract::f() {
  // Do something
}

class Concrete : public Abstract {
public:
  void f() {
    Abstract::f();  // call base class implementation
    // Do something more
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that explains the notion of pure functions

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual void what() const = 0;
};

void A::what() const 
{ 
    std::cout << "struct A"; 
}

struct B : A
{
    virtual void what() const = 0;
};

void B::what() const 
{ 
    A::what();
    std::cout << ", struct B : A"; 
}

struct C : B
{
    void what() const;
};

void C::what() const 
{ 
    B::what();
    std::cout << ", struct C: B"; 
}


int main() 
{
//  A a; compiler error
//  B b; compiler error
    C c;

    const A &rc = c;

    rc.what();
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
struct A, struct B : A, struct C: B
```

In this example classes A and B are abstract because they have a pure virtual function though each of them provides the corresponding definition of their pure virtual function.

And only class C is not abstract because it redeclares the virtual function as a non-pure virtual function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to instantiate the inherited class, i.e. to create an object of this type, you must have all pure virtual methods implemented in the inherited class.

In other words, the pure virtual methods not only define the class interface but also force you to provide their actual implementation.